# Taylor expanding onto a deformed sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

Suppose I have a deformed unit sphere whose shape is given by $ r(r, \theta, \phi) = 1 + \epsilon x_iA_{ij}x_j$  for $\epsilon << 1$ and $A_{ij}$ is a symmetric traceless second order tensor.

How can I Taylor expand any scalar or vector function near sphere? That is, I want to find $\psi_{1+\delta r}$ and $\delta r = \epsilon x_iA_{ij}x_j$. I assume it would involve the higher order derivatives of tensor $A$?

Is there a general way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is totally unclear starting with your notion of a deformed sphere.